# Possible to get data source from textbox?

Tags: vb.net, datasource, oledb

I have now the code below

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Syral.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0
```

I would like to get the data source from a textbox, is this possible?

thanks

Comment: Replace `C:\Syral.xlsx` with the value in the TextBox.  Consider using the [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But the user should just select the file and the data source must refer to the textbox and get the path out of the textbox.

Comment: It's unclear where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & textbox1.text & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
```